# Clear text from label before executing new function

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a doubt regarding this situation, in my program I use a label to put a text inside when search_button (which is a button is executed). But, everytime I update or I press again, I get the new text overlapped in the test label.

How can I remove text from label before overwriting it? I tried it by saying `test = label(text = '')`, but it does not work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

root = Tk()
root.title('Stock Searcher')
root.geometry("800x600")
db_name = 'materiales.db'

def run_query(query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result


def searchnow(search_box):
    selected = drop.get()
    test = Label(text = '')
    test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
    if selected == 'Search by...':
        test = Label(text = 'Search by... is not an option')
        test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
        return
    if selected == 'Name':
        if search_box == '':
            test = Label(text = 'Write material Name')
            test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
            return
        query = 'SELECT totalstock FROM StocksBatch WHERE name = ? ORDER BY MovementID DESC LIMIT 1'
        parameters = (search_box,)
        result = run_query(query, parameters)        
        totalstock = result.fetchall()
        if len(totalstock) == 0:
            test = Label(text = 'Material Name do not exist in database')
            test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
            return
        totalstock = float(totalstock[0][0])
        message = 'Total stock is {}'.format(totalstock)
        test = Label(text = message)
        test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
    if selected == 'Batch Number':
        test = Label(text = 'Search by... is not an option')
        test.grid(row = 3, column= 0)
        return
    

#entry box stocks
search_box = Entry()
search_box.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

search_box_label = Label(text = 'Search Stocks by ...')
search_box_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

message = Label(text = '', fg = 'red') 
message.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

search_button = Button(text = 'Search Stocks', command = lambda: searchnow(search_box.get()))
search_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

#dropdownbox

drop = ttk.Combobox(value = ['Search by...', 'Name', 'Batch Number', 'Warehouse ID', 'Aisle ID', 'Bin ID', 'W-A-B ID'])
drop.current(0)
drop.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: Can you use the `.destroy() ` method on the label ?

Comment: Don't keep creating new labels. Create the label once, and then use the `configure` method to clear it, or  to replace it with a new string.

Answer (score 1):

To clear a text from a label, use `label.config(text='')`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def clear():
    label.config(text='')


def change():
    label.config(text='changed text')


label = Label(text='default text')
buttonA = Button(root, text='clear text', command=clear)
buttonB = Button(root, text='change text', command=change)

label.pack()
buttonA.pack()
buttonB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```